# Java encoding String to cp1251

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have project in 'windows-1251' encoding. 
And next code print me 'P©' instead 'Щ':

```
  String var = "Щ";
  Println(var);
```

I try to convert this String in byte[] format and get different results but there are not correctly. 
How can I print  my primary symbol?

Comment: Can you try `System.out.println("\u0429");`?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle  I should get this code at runtime. How can I do this?

Comment: If u want to use the default windows encoding than use 
`var = new String("Щ".getBytes(),Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(var);`      http://www.browxy.com/SubmittedCode/443470

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera This code also get me "Р©".

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify source encoding. In maven you do [this like](https://maven.apache.org/general.html):

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>CP-1251</project.build.sourceEncoding>
```

But it's generally bad idea to use anything other than UTF-8 nowadays...